# JS: window.setInterval still running in the background?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is like:

```
window.setInterval(updateSeconds, 1000);
function updateSeconds() {
    var remainingSeconds = $('#seconds').html() - 1;
    if(remainingSeconds < 0) {
        remainingSeconds = 0;
    }
    $('#seconds').html(remainingSeconds);
    if(remainingSeconds == 0) {
        //stop calling updateSeconds
    }
}
```

There is no issue, except that setInterval will still keep calling updateSeconds(), is there a way to stop it?

Comment: You can also use setTimeout as a replacement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) to stop a timer:

```
// Added `var handle`:
var handle = window.setInterval(updateSeconds, 1000);
function updateSeconds() {
    var remainingSeconds = $('#seconds').html() - 1;
    if(remainingSeconds < 0) {
        remainingSeconds = 0;
    }
    $('#seconds').html(remainingSeconds);
    if(remainingSeconds == 0) {
        //stop calling updateSeconds
        window.clearInterval(handle);  // <== added
        handle = 0;                    // <== added
    }
}
```

If your code is at global scope, you probably don't want to create a new global variable called `handle`. You can avoid that by wrapping it in a function and then executing the function immediately:

```
(function() {
    var handle = window.setInterval(updateSeconds, 1000);
    function updateSeconds() {
        var remainingSeconds = $('#seconds').html() - 1;
        if(remainingSeconds < 0) {
            remainingSeconds = 0;
        }
        $('#seconds').html(remainingSeconds);
        if(remainingSeconds == 0) {
            //stop calling updateSeconds
            window.clearInterval(handle);
            handle = 0;
        }
    }
})();
```

Now `handle` and `updateSeconds` are private to the anonymous function. (Obviously if you need to call `updateSeconds` from somewhere else, making it private would be a problem.)

But if they're already inside something (an event handler function, perhaps), you've already got a private scope there and don't need to do that.